# Obtener backup full de una base de datos en PostgreSql mediante un cron

Tags: postgresql, cron

Estoy intentando programar un cron que respalde las bases de datos que tengo en PostgreSQL.
Ejecuté en la terminal la sentencia: `pg_dump -U carolina  -W t3st > /tmp/Pruebahoy1.sql` , sin embargo, cuando lo quiero ejecutar desde un cron únicamente crea el archivo pero no respalda nada y manda el siguiente error:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump: invalid option -- '4'
```

Me podrían orientar si cambia algún parámetro al ejecutar desde un cron y/o terminal, por favor?

Comment: La -W es para pedir el password, como lo pasas en cron? lo otro, estas segura que es el mismo comando, pues la opción 4 la veo en el primer

Comment: En el cron guardo el password en una variable:                                      #!/bin/bash -x
FECHA=`/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
USER='carolina'
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'

pg_dump -U carolina  -W $PASSWORD t3st > /tmp/Pruebahoy1.sql

Comment: Usa para eso la variable de entorno PGPASSWORD, pues creo que como lo tienes no te va a funcionar, mira la documentación https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html.

es muy probable que tu password tenga un 4 ;-)

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, he logrado obtener el dump